# AddIdentityCore and IDataProtectorProvider in .NET Identity

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

When using .NET Identity, while registering services, if I call `AddDefaultTokenProviders` method after using `AddIdentityCore` it throws this error:

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider)
```

But if I call it with `AddIdentity` is works fine.

I generally understand difference between the two, and I've looked into source code for both but I just can't seem to find what specifically doesn't work for `DataProtectorTokenProvider` with first approach. Is there a way of making `AddIdentityCore` work with default token providers? And what exactly is the difference?